# History.Push affects all tabs instead of current tab

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I'm working on code that handles session expiration for a site. After session expires, I'm using history.push to redirect the user to the logout page.

Currently, this behavior redirects all open tabs to the logout page. How can I isolate history.push to only affect the current tab?

```
const redirectToLogoutPage = () => history.push("/user/logout");
if (loggedInAsEmail) {
 handleLogout({}, redirectToLogoutPage());
 }
};
```

Comment: Can you share some code so we can see the implementation?

Comment: sorry didn't upload properly. I've just edited in. That snippet is the gist; the conditional runs when the timer for the session expires.

Comment: What does the `handleLogout` function look like? It looks like you are invoking the `redirectToLogoutPage` and passing in the result. Is that your intention?